# Why is my Candy Box 2 load counting down candies by 10?

Tags: candy-box-2

I loaded a Candy Box 2 game from a text save and my candies started counting down to zero.

I cleared my cache and this did not change anything.

Have you heard of this bug? Is there anyway to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: do you have any lolligators in the lollipop farm?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you sure you haven't enabled the lolligators? Lolligators can cause a net loss of candy, which is probably your problem.

Comment: This should be a comment, but i see you do not have the ability to comment.

Comment: Ah didn't no they consumed candies, that was it thanks!

Comment: @JamieRead If this was the right answer, mark it with a tick. You'll get reputation!

Answer (score -1):

You might have enabled the Lolligators.